# SVG Text blurry in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, svg-filters, svgpanzoom

I have two examples with a an SVG and some text with a SVG filter, where the text is shown blurry in Firefox. In the Chrome browser the text with the applied filter is sharp.

The SVG is used as a map and therefore the first example uses this SVG-Pan-Zoom library (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom)

Example 1: http://plnkr.co/edit/P4o7JUY4fNg5DDzF3QiD?p=preview

Interestingly, when panning the map, the text appears sharp for a short time.

For the second example, I was able to reconstruct the issue by only having the SVG in the HTML, without any Javascript involved.

Example 2: http://plnkr.co/edit/UJMMFS5hGTIzesWXFf1Q?p=preview

Here is the filter:

```
<filter id="drop_shadow">
  <feFlood flood-color="white" result="flood"/>
  <feOffset id="offset_1" dx="-3.0" dy="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="offset1"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="flood" in2="offset1" result="shadow1"/>
  <feOffset id="offset_2" dx="0" dy="3.0" in="SourceAlpha" result="offset2"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="flood" in2="offset2" result="shadow2"/>
  <feOffset id="offset_3" dx="3.0" dy="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="offset3"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="flood" in2="offset3" result="shadow3"/>
  <feOffset id="offset_4" dx="0" dy="-3.0" in="SourceAlpha" result="offset4"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="flood" in2="offset4" result="shadow4"/>
  <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="shadow1"/>
    <feMergeNode in="shadow2"/>
    <feMergeNode in="shadow3"/>
    <feMergeNode in="shadow4"/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

This is the text element:

```
<text font-size="51.999999852629884" class="map-text" 
      x="2290.25362319" y="2501.0326087" filter="url(#drop_shadow)" 
      style="font-family: DejaVuSansBook,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
      text-anchor: middle; pointer-events: none; stroke-linecap: butt; 
      stroke-linejoin: miter;">Some Text</text>
```

Any ideas how I could fix this issue, so the text is always sharp in Firefox? Could it be because of the transformation that is applied to the svg by the pan and zoom library? The transformation looks like:

```
<g id="viewport-20160105141350663" 
   transform="matrix(0.33444816053511706,0,0,0.33444816053511706,-517.7257525083612,-343.97993311036794)">
```

This can be seen in the second example.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a recent version of Firefox? It looks fine for me (v43.0.3). There is a small difference between how it renders in Chrome and Firefox but this is attributable to different anti-aliasing between the browsers. You could control this with the text-rendering attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering

Comment: I just installed v43.0.3 on Windows an can still see the issue. It is especially good visible in the first example, when panning the map. The moment, you pan the map, the text gets sharper. But yah, interestingly its much worse under Ubuntu with v43.0.0.

I also tried the text-rendering attributes, but they don't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas but just FYI on OSX with 43.0.3 they look pretty much identical Chrome/Firefox, panning/not-panning.